# Run Automation When A Data Extension is Updated

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, list, automationstudio

I have an external system that accesses Marketing Cloud to send an email, we are selecting users from that external system and then it updates a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud moments before it attempts to send. Our current problem is that new additions to that DE are not being sent to because the external system also double checks the All-Subscribers list which is causing an error.

So... what I would like to do is either ***instantly trigger an automation when that specific data extension is triggered to update the all subscribers list*** or find a way to concurrently update both when the API call is executed. Any insight on this?

Comment: You have to set this up concurrently, starting an automation via SOAP API:
https://github.com/sfmcdg/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/starting-an-automation.md - the automation needs a schedule event for this, but should not be enabled. Basically, when you can press "run once", the automation is ready to be called via SOAP.